# Jmeter Windows Authentication error - 401

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to record an internal website for which i need to enter credentials that is not same as the windows credential. Later on the same test needs to be run for more than one user. i know how to use the csv file to pass the parameters - username and password.

For Windows Authentication i have added Authorization manager.

From Fiddler i checked it was NTLM authentication(though i am not sure yet) and i did enter the values for NTLM authentication in Authorization Manager.

Now when i try and record the internal website - i cannot even go to homepage after the windows credentials, it keeps on spinning.

When i check the Authorization Manager, i find an extra line added for kerberos Authentication as shown in Picture:
[image]

My query here is:
1)why is it recording it as kerberos
2)where is it saving the username and password
3)why is it not loading the website- always keeps spinning and i have to stop it
4)I have tried Kerberos settings and then record, but its not working either , could it be i am using the wrong values in the kerb5.conf file , how do i debug.

Kind of stuck at the moment.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're uncertain what authentication is being used under the hood - just ask around, application developers or network administrators should be aware of the external authentication scheme. You can also try using a 3rd-party tool like [Kerberos Authentication Tester](http://blog.michelbarneveld.nl/media/p/33.aspx)

I don't think you can record and replay Windows authentication so it makes sense to start recording some time **after** the login screen as long as you can login using JMeter

1. Looking into [JMeter source](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/proxy/ProxyControl.java#L671)

   ```
   // if HEADER_AUTHORIZATION contains "Basic"
   // then set Mechanism.BASIC_DIGEST, otherwise Mechanism.KERBEROS
   ```
2. In case of Kerberos credentials are saved directly in the [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) in form of `${AUTH_LOGIN}` and `${AUTH_PASSWORD}`, real credentials are not stored anywhere
3. Most probably your application doesn't receive valid authentication context therefore it cannot proceed
4. Add `sun.security.krb5.debug=true` line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation), JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

   More information:

   - [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)
   - [JAAS and Java GSS-API Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/index.html)

Comment: I am able to work it out by adding the steps manually and replaying it and it passes , but recording is still not working . it just keeps on trying the same page. I am trying to record only after logged in. Not sure where it is going wrong.